# No file creation/modified date when a file created using HTTP PUT in java/Android

Tags: android, file, http, attributes, put

I am developing an app for android that reads/write to a wireless device using HTTP PUT.

Is there a way to set the creation/modified date & time attribute of a file being created by HTTP PUT because at the moment the file is created fine but with no attributes (creation datetime, modified datetime.

Let me know if you need some code snippet.(not sure what will help)

Could this be a fallback of the device i.e. the device is responsible for adding these attributes to a file?

I have tried searching the net but this problem is hard to explain in 1 line/few words :)

Thanks in advance.

Edit: Just to clarify, the file that I am trying to write already exists so HTTP PUT is simply overriding it.(simple text file). and So I just pass a BYTEARRAY entity to be written to this file. But somehow in this process, the file attributes are getting lost.

Edit: Following is the uploadFile code snippet.
    private void uploadFile(String data){

```
   try{
          HttpClient http = new DefaultHttpClient(); //declare and initialize the HTTP client.
          //Using HTTP PUT, upload the data to the Settings file
          HttpPut putmethod = new HttpPut("http://airstash.net/files/SETTINGS.TXT"); 
          putmethod.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(data.getBytes("iso-8859-1")));
          putmethod.setHeader("Content_Type", "Text/Plain");
          HttpResponse response = http.execute(putmethod); //Execute the PUT request and receive response.
          if(response!= null)
          {
   //Show the response code (for testing only)
        String responsecode = Integer.toString(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responsecode, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

What's wrong with [`file.setLastModified(long)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#setLastModified%28long%29)?

Some old reports that it doesn't work but appears to be fixed.

I can't find any information on setting the creation date because the creation date should be set when the file was created automatically.

Comment: Hi citizen, Since the file is being read and written using HTTP GET and PUT, so I cant access the file properties. I will modify my question to make it more clear. Thanks

Comment: I actually would like to see a code snippet of the part where you are sending the data

Comment: Have just added the code relating to the file upload (file downloading is fine)

Comment: what if you create a local file first, out of your bytearray, assign a modified date, and then put the bytearray of the file?

Comment: Just tried it, dint work either. Thanks for your help but I think I will need to talk to the hardware guys for my device.